# I am down voting and still not losing reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I down voted two days back on a closed question. Didn't lose any points.
Today I down voted yet another not closed question. Didn't lose any points.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There has been a change.

Downvotes on *questions* no longer cost the voter any reputation.

Downvotes on *answers* still cost the caster 1 rep.

Comment: Ohh Eye See! Thanks!